# Frequently Parsing and Storing text with PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, text

I am creating a php script that parses a string of text typically 500-750  characters using regex expressions to find 5-6 substrings. The extracted info is manipulated a bit and then stored in a database. Once implemented, the script will be executed every few seconds on average throughout the day. Will an average webserver be able to handle this level of usage? I'm not sure how memory intensive this type of script would be with the frequency its executed.

I was thinking through possible ways of reducing the load on the server and came up with an idea which i'm not sure is any better. Instead of parsing the raw text instantly when received, I could store it in a database to be parsed later. Throughout the day I could then have the server process the info in manageable quantities and during periods of low site traffic. If this is a solution, would the below algorithm be an okay way to approach it?

1. Select a few text records which have yet to be parsed from a database
2. Extract info from the text and add them to the database
3. Update the text records to indicate they've been parsed
4. Have the script reload using `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`
5. Repeat x amount of times

Any advice on how to approach this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound like a very expensive application. But it's really not possible to predict without knowing the full load on your server and what the parser is actually doing. You'll probably have to implement it and see how well it performs. If it can't keep up, then redesign it.

Comment: A processing pool is likely overkill. Run your script through a profiler to see if there's any need for optimization or worrying. Chances are every few seconds won't have an impact in comparison to regular page requests.

Answer (score 0):

From you description it doesn't seem like something very demanding on the server.

I'd recommend to implement the simplest solution for parsing and storing data. Then feed this piece of code with load of data and measure throughput. This can give you some clue how fast can you process the records.

After this you can estimate if this simple approach is sufficient or not.